# Has any research been done to solve word searches with AI?

Tags: ai-design

A simple word search seems too simple to solve with a computer AI. But what I'm interested is how human's solve it. They build up strategies over the course of solving the puzzle. For example:

1) first just look to see if any words "jump out".
2) look for the horizontal words.
3) look for the letter "O"
4) look for the letter "p" next to a letter "o"
5) methodically look along rows and columns and diagonals. 
6) cross off words
7) take the first letter of a word in the list and put it in memory.

Things of that sort. I would like to build such a program. With built in search capabilities, some of which are faster than others. And the AI can combine different search methods and try to solve the puzzle as fast as possible.

It should also store strategies that work. Or think about why strategies work sometimes and not others.

I would like to read a bit more about AI and strategies if you know any good references?